# Macro variable resolving with special Characters

Tags: macros, sas

I am trying to pass a macro variable created by Call symputx that has a special character(an underscore), however not able to succeed, here is the code I wrote.

```
data _null_; 
    call symputx('name', scan( "&table" ,2,'.')); run; 

%let location= E:\drives\Monthly; 

Proc export data=file
outfile= "&location.\&name..txt"  dbms=dlm replace; 
run;
```

When the NAME macro variable has no special characters, the code executes perfectly, however it shows authentification failure or doesnt resolve the macro or any other error.

I am missing to mask the special chars, how I do proceed here?

So here are the details: (added from comment by @Richard)

```
%let location=%nrstr(E:\Reports\Monthly\Updates (NEW)_UPPDATE_LIST);
%let Name = %nrstr(Table_20);
Proc export dbms=dlm 
  data=Newfile 
  replace
  outfile= "&location=.\&Name..txt" ;
run;
```

When I have underscore in the table name it gives this Error

```
ERROR: Insufficient authorization to access
E:\Reports\Monthly\Updates (NEW)_UPPDATE_LIST
```

I will have to add one thing is that I am using %include statement to run the program.

Comment: what are the special characters name could have

Comment: only underscore

Comment: I tried with %let table =new._one; and it worked for me

Comment: The only special character in &NAME that would cause trouble for SAS would be `"` since that would lead to generating invalid SAS syntax.  There could be other characters that are not special to SAS but are invalid as part of a filename on your operating system.  Like `:`.  What characters are causing you problems?

Comment: @Tom I have only underscore there in table name, and in location i have ( ) but that resolves when I take away the underscore in table name.

Comment: Show actual input data. Show actual lines from your SAS log with the error that SAS is generating.

Comment: So here are the details:

%let location=%nrstr(E:\Reports\Monthly\Updates (NEW)\_UPPDATE_LIST);
%let Name = %nrstr(Table_20); 

Proc export data=Newfile
outfile= "&location=.\&Name..txt"   dbms=dlm replace; 
run;

When I have underscore in the table name it gives this Error

ERROR: Insufficient authorization to access E:\Reports\Monthly\Updates (NEW)\_UPPDATE_LIST

I will have to add one thing is that I am using %include statement to run the program.

Comment: "Insufficient authorization" is not a problem with the code.  It's saying you don't have permission to access it.  Does the folder exist?  Looks like you may have a typo, "UPPDATE" should be "UPDATE"?

Comment: I don't think you can insert an equal sign into a filename. Try `outfile="&location\&name..txt"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`NRSTR` is a macro quoting function and it's resolution into normal tokenization during SAS interpretation of the code input stream may require `UNQUOTE`

> [%STR and %NRSTR Functions](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001061290.htm)
>
> Using %STR and %NRSTR Functions
>
> If a special character or mnemonic affects the way the macro processor
>   constructs macro program statements, you must mask the item during
>   macro compilation (or during the compilation of a macro program
>   statement in open code) by using either the %STR or %NRSTR macro
>   quoting functions.

and

> [%UNQUOTE Function](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000543618.htm)
>
> During macro execution, unmasks all special characters and mnemonic
>   operators for a value.

Answer (score -1):

I guess the problem is related with permission to directory. See the permission to directory to make sure you have access.